# Websphere Liberty ClassNotFoundException during validation

Tags: java, classloader, bean-validation, websphere-liberty

Using Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.7 with features

- `beanValidation-1.1` enabled
- `jpa-2.1` **disabled**

The JPA-2.0 hibernate implementation is being loaded as project dependency though in the project. Validator is autowired by Spring framework similar to

```
Validation.byDefaultProvider()
  .configure()
  .buildValidatorFactory()
  .getValidator()
```

Seems that it configures the default traversable resolver which further delegates the work to Jpa traversable resolver as I have JPA API in the classpath. Still, when doing a validation on an object, it fails with `ClassNotFoundException: javax/persistence/Persistence` due to call usage of this class in [`org.apache.bval.jsr.resolver.JPATraversableResolver:34`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.apache.bval$bval-jsr@1.1.0@org$apache$bval$jsr$resolver$JPATraversableResolver.java#34).

Seems as WebSphere bug related with class loaders, but maybe I'm supposed to initialize the validation some other way?

There is no such problem though when I enable the `jpa-2.1` feature in Websphere.

Comment: If you want applications to have visibility to `javax.persistence.*` classes you will need to have *some* jpa feature enabled.  When you say you have `jpa-2.1` disabled, are you then enabling `jpa-2.0`?  These features should be providing the JPA classes.

Comment: I load `jpa-2.0` as a Maven dependency not as a Websphere feature. It seems that because of it there is a partial visibility to `javax.persistence.*`. I would expect that Websphere either doesn't see it from the bean validation code at all or sees it in both places – validator initialization and validation itself.

Comment: try adding `<feature>jpa-2.0</feature>` to your server.xml, that should resolve your issue

Comment: @aguibert, I will be not comfortable knowing that I have two JPA implementations in my classpath.

Comment: Do you have Apache BVal on your classpath as well? It seems so by the use of org.apache.bval.jsr.resolver.JPATraversableResolver. Until recently (June 2015) BVal did not even have a Bean Validation 1.1 compliant release. I am a bit confused about your used dependencies. Maybe you could clarify that a bit.

Comment: `beanValidation-1.1` Websphere feature adds this dependency. Apparently the Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.7 uses the BVal from June (see link to the code source in my question).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `javax.persistence.*` is being provided at compile time via the Maven dependency, but this will not carry over into the server runtime.
In order to have `javax.persistence.*` be provided to the server runtime, you will need to enable `jpa-2.0` or `jpa-2.1` in the server.xml, or you could write a user feature that provides `javax.persistence.*`.

In the comments you mentioned you did not want to have two JPA implementations on your classpath.  By default `jpa-2.0` will give you an OpenJPA implementation and `jpa-2.1` will give you an EclipseLink implementation.  However, you can override this so there is only one JPA implementation on your runtime classpath.  Since you are using Hibernate, you can still enable `jpa-2.0` or `jpa-2.1` and override the provider so that only *one* JPA implementation will be available on the server runtime.

See this article for how to set Hibernate to be the JPA provider for Liberty:
[Hibernate JPA sample: Using an alternative JPA provider](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/osi-Java_Persistence_API_JPA_Hibernate_Sample)
It has a sample server.xml and web application including source that should serve as a good example.

The key here is that you specify this in the **server.xml**:

```
<jpa defaultPersistenceProvider="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
```

OR, you specify this in the **persistence.xml**:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Comment: Maybe it's Websphere's problem, but I can't install the jpa-2.0 feature.

Comment: Can't install or can't enable? The jpa-2.0 feature should be included in the base 8.5.5.7 image. You shouldn't have to install anything additional.

Comment: Seems I could not install the feature due to the missing proxy configuration. But do you honestly think that this is a Websphere defect that different class loading is done under bean validation configuration and in the runtime?